# Split dataframe into two based on numeric and integer type in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to split a dataframe into `df1` and `df2` based on data type `numeric` and `integer`.

The `df1` and `df2` will respectively contain `"bmi", "age", "cal", "pro"` and `"male", "urban"`.

```
sapply(df, class)
```

Out:

```
      bmi       age       cal       pro      male 
"numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "integer" 
    urban 
"integer" 

str(df)
```

Out:

```
'data.frame':   4825 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ bmi  : num  24.7 25.3 22.8 21.7 24.2 ...
 $ age  : num  37.5 36.5 37 36.9 40 ...
 $ cal  : num  6.31 1.84 3.87 2.67 1.59 ...
 $ pro  : num  13.57 13.43 9.57 12.51 11.65 ...
 $ male : int  1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ urban: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

How can I do that in R? Thank you.

I try with `unlist(lapply(df, is.numeric))`, but it doesn't distingue `numeric` and `integer`.

**Update:**

With the code below I get a dataframe but it's not a subset of `df`, another problem is `interger` columns included:

```
numeric <- which(sapply(df,is.numeric))
df1 <- as.data.frame(numeric)
print(df1)
```

Out:

[image]

Comment: `split.default(df, sapply(df, class))`. Use `list2env` if you want to get it out of a `list` and into your global environment.

Comment: Thank you but how to set `df1` and `df2`?

Comment: Using `list2env(your_list, .GlobalEnv)`. You'll probably want to rename the items in the `list` before you do that.

Comment: Not an exact dupe, but similar concept here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35747729/1270695

Comment: `df1, df2 <- split.default(df, sapply(df, class))`?

Comment: 1) `out <- split.default(df, sapply(df, class))`. 2) `names(out) <- paste0('df', seq_along(out))` 3) `list2env(out, .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 you should probably add it as an answer. Can't find an exact dupe to split based on `class`.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. If you like to answer the question, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works, many thanks to @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 and @Ronak Shah.

```
out <- split.default(df, sapply(df, class))
names(out) <- paste0('df', seq_along(out))
names(out) 
list2env(out, .GlobalEnv)
```