# How to get R to automatically select and group columns?

Tags: r

I have 144 columns, and was wondering how I can have R select the first 4 columns, group them as another data frame, then get R to repeat the same for the subsequent 4 columns until all 144 columns are grouped as 36 separate data frames? I guess the real problem I have is having R do the grouping work automatically than me repeating the process manually 36 times... The names of the columns are random so I cannot exploit patterns of column names...

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46189799/split-dataframe-every-two-columns-into-multiple-dataframe and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747729/how-to-split-a-data-frame-into-multiple-dataframes-with-each-two-columns-as-a-ne

Answer (score 3):

Edited answer.  If your dataframe name is `df` do this

```
list2env(split.default(df, paste0('df', (1 + (seq_along(df) - 1) %/% 4 ))), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Let's create a `df` with 144 columns

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(144*5), 5))
#store number of columns in n
n <- ncol(df)
```

Now proceed as follows to create 36 data.frames named `df1` to `df36`

```
library(purrr)
list2env(setNames(map(1:(n/4), ~(df[, (1 +(seq_along(df) -1) %/% 4) == .])), paste0("df", 1:(n/4))), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

[image]

Explanation-

- `purrr::map` function creates a list with 36 elements (n/4) each with a dataset of 4 columns grouped as intended.  I have used `%/%` i.e. integer division in this regard. ( check `0:143 %/% 4`)
- Column names are not used
- resulting list will have unnamed elements
- `setNames` will thus create names of each elemnt of list
- `list2env` thus saves all elements of list into separate dfs.

You can do this completely in baseR also, but the syntax will be quite verbose.  replace `map(1:(n/4), ~(df[, (1 +(seq_along(df) -1) %/% 4) == .]))` with `Map(f = function(x){(df[, (1 +(seq_along(df) -1) %/% 4) == x])}, 1:(n/4))` to get a complete syntax like this

```
list2env(
  setNames(
    Map(f = function(x){(df[, (1 +(seq_along(df) -1) %/% 4) == x])}, 
        1:(n/4)), 
    paste0("df", 1:(n/4))), 
  envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Isn't this what you've expected?  Please tell if the problem is still not solved, as you haven't accepted any of the answers!

Comment: thanks for your kind reply - I am still trying to figure it out, but I really appreciate your input :)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to columns by index, so:

```
library(tidyverse)

sourceDF <- tibble(
  x1=runif(5), x2=runif(5), x3=runif(5), x4=runif(5),
  x5=runif(5), x6=runif(5), x7=runif(5), x8=runif(5),
  x9=runif(5), x10=runif(5), x11=runif(5), x12=runif(5),
)


lapply(
  seq(1, ncol(sourceDF), 4),
  function(x) {
    sourceDF %>% select(all_of(x:(x+3)))
  }
)
[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
     x1    x2    x3    x4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 0.997 0.733 0.614 0.933
2 0.881 0.948 0.860 0.462
3 0.772 0.410 0.359 0.694
4 0.977 0.282 0.856 0.321
5 0.976 0.421 0.405 0.493

[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
     x5    x6    x7     x8
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 0.773 0.137 0.416 0.228 
2 0.161 0.844 0.358 0.990 
3 0.840 0.629 0.960 0.724 
4 0.115 0.751 0.404 0.847 
5 0.794 0.267 0.767 0.0887

[[3]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
     x9    x10    x11    x12
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 0.705 0.0265 0.907  0.0610
2 0.402 0.829  0.279  0.723 
3 0.348 0.239  0.0203 0.483 
4 0.870 0.695  0.543  0.782 
5 0.532 0.475  0.543  0.0521
```

Comment: Thanks heaps- but do you know how I can save individual responses as one data frame?

Comment: Wrap the `lapply()` in `bind_rows()`.

Comment: Thanks - I will try that :)